# Split string issues with null position

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I have a string of the days of the week. I parse it in C# and store each day in a separate variable.  For example:

```
string weekdayName = "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun";
```

And the I split them using ',' as a delimiter:

```
var weekDayName = weekDay.Split(',');
var firstDay = weekDayName[0];
var secondDay = weekDayName[1];
var thirdDay = weekDayName[2];
var fourthDay = weekDayName[3];
var fifthDay =  weekDayName[4];
var sixDay = weekDayName[5];
var seventhDay = weekDayName[6];
```

Everything works. However, the string dynamically changes. A user assigns the days of the week. For example a string weekDayName could only contain "Mon,Tue". But the problem i'm running into is if not all the position contains value it will fail.

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I have tried:

```
if (weekDayName[5].Length >0)
{
    var sixDay = weekDayName[5];
}
```

But it still fails...

How can I check and grab the value of the existing data, if some of the position are missing I just ignore them?

What I'm trying to achieve is:

```
DateTime currentDay = new DateTime();
currentDay = DateTime.Now;

if (currentDay.ToString("ddd") == firstDay || currentDay.ToString("ddd") == seconday)
{
    // I will check the currentDay against every day of the week
    //do something
}
```

Comment: this check `if (weekDayName[5].Length >0)` should be `if (weekDayName.Length > 0)`. Currently you are trying to check the length of string, not the length of array. But there must be a better way to handle that, why not use [DayOfWeek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) enum

Comment: I'm curious why you're trying to parse out this data when DateTime provides it for you :)

Comment: Pheonixblade9, I'm actually getting that string from a registry.

Comment: "I'm actually getting that string from a registry" God be with ye.

Comment: So what do you do with `firstDay`, `secondDay`, `thirdDay`, ... ? Why can'y you have a `string[] days` that you use?

Comment: I use those variables later on in the code to check and see if the current day is within that range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your index out of range is not coming from where you think. I am of course assuming this since you tried to check length on an element that was never set if the user enters `Mon,Tue`.

```
var enteredDays = weekDay.Split(',');
for(var i = 0; i < enteredDays.Length; i++)
{
    var day = enteredDays[i];
    if(i == 0)
       first = day;
    else if(i == 1)
       second = day;

    ... etc....
}
```

Now you can check `String.IsNullOrEmpty(..yourDay..)` when you need to use the values you pulled from the array. You can't use `.Length` on them because they are `null` and will blow up unless you default them all to `string.Empty`.

Answer (score 0):

There must be some smarter way of doing this, but since i do not know where the string originates from, it is hard for me to make a better solution.

However, given the current requirements, you could do something like:

```
string weekdayName = "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun";

List<String> weekDaysList = weekdayName.Split(',').ToList();

foreach (var weekDay in weekDaysList.Take(2))
{
       if (weekDay == DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd"))
       {
              // do something
              break;
       }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to try Linq (which is a language feature of C# 3.5 and higher, just include the `System.Linq namespace`) you could do it like this:

```
string[] names = weekdayName
    .Split(',')
    .Select(s => s.Trim())
    .Where(s => s.Length > 0)
    .ToArray();
```

The `names` array now contains all non-empty day names, without any leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Wow that's a lot of code for a simple check, As mentioned by other members you can use LINQ to merge all validations in single query something like :

```
string weekdayName = "Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat,Sun";
var wc = weekdayName.Split(',');

if (wc.Any(str => str.Contains(DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek.ToString().Substring(0,3))))
{

}
```

Try this and let me know if you have any concerns.